# Excel Shade Between 4 Lines

Tags: excel, fill, line-plot, stacked-area-chart

I am trying to shade between 4 lines on a line plot in Excel. I have figured out how to shade between two lines or the min and the max of the data. I need to know how to shade between the 3rd and 1st quartiles or between the two red lines in the plot below. So the final plot will have a shade color between the 1st and 3rd quartiles and a *different* shade color between the min and the max lines.

[image: Excel 2 Shaded/Filled Line Plot]

I have used "stacked area" to achieve the shading between the min and max lines in the plot above. The other lines at the moment are "Line" chart type. I've tried lots of combinations w/out success trying to shade between the 1st and 3rd quartiles. My data looks like this:

```
Month   Median  1st Qrtle   3rd Qrtle   MIN MAX maxmindff   2020    2021
Jan     7.07    6.75    7.43    5.85    8.38    2.53    7.19    6.70
Feb     7.16    6.83    7.64    5.95    8.30    2.35    7.43    7.18
Mar     7.43    7.07    7.75    6.09    8.49    2.40    7.60    7.94
Apr     7.67    7.37    7.98    6.62    8.76    2.14    7.42    7.63
May     7.29    6.91    7.56    6.27    8.35    2.08    7.26    7.17
Jun     6.78    6.47    7.19    6.01    7.90    1.89    7.31    6.51
Jul     6.26    6.04    6.56    5.49    7.20    1.71    6.38    5.97
Aug     5.95    5.73    6.23    5.30    6.62    1.31    6.25    6.29
Sep     6.34    6.07    6.63    5.44    7.20    1.75    6.51    6.56
Oct     6.94    6.62    7.22    6.00    7.79    1.80        
Nov     7.08    6.72    7.44    6.10    8.18    2.08        
Dec     7.00    6.73    7.36    6.08    8.12    2.04
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this. Here are the steps: 1) Arrange your excel data with the first column the exact data values - in my case it's the "min" values. 2) Next column of excel data is the calculated 1st quartile - min for each Jan - Dec row. 3) The next column of data is median time series - 1st quartile. 4) Next column is 3rd quartile - median. 5) next column of excel data is max time series - 3rd quartile. 6) plot these columns along with the "min" column as a stacked area. 7) Change the fill area below the 'min' line to 'no fill'. 8) Send all of these stacked area time series to the second y axis. 9) Add the other time series as line plots and use the primary axis. 10) delete or designate 'no line' for any time series that you don't want to show on the final plot. Here below is my final plot.

[image]

Here's what the data looks like -

```
    min 1st quartile    3rd quartile    min max 
Jan 5.85    0.91    0.32    0.36    0.95    
Feb 5.95    0.87    0.34    0.48    0.66    
Mar 6.09    0.98    0.36    0.32    0.73    
Apr 6.62    0.75    0.30    0.31    0.78    
May 6.27    0.64    0.38    0.27    0.79    
Jun 6.01    0.46    0.31    0.41    0.71    
Jul 5.49    0.54    0.23    0.29    0.65    
Aug 5.30    0.43    0.22    0.27    0.39    
Sep 5.44    0.63    0.26    0.29    0.56    
Oct 6.00    0.63    0.32    0.28    0.58    
Nov 6.10    0.62    0.36    0.36    0.74    
Dec 6.08    0.65    0.27    0.36    0.76    
                        
    min 1st quartile    min max 2020    2021
Jan 5.85    6.75    7.43    8.38    7.19    6.70
Feb 5.95    6.83    7.64    8.30    7.43    7.18
Mar 6.09    7.07    7.75    8.49    7.60    7.94
Apr 6.62    7.37    7.98    8.76    7.42    7.63
May 6.27    6.91    7.56    8.35    7.26    7.17
Jun 6.01    6.47    7.19    7.90    7.31    6.51
Jul 5.49    6.04    6.56    7.20    6.38    5.97
Aug 5.30    5.73    6.23    6.62    6.25    6.29
Sep 5.44    6.07    6.63    7.20    6.51    6.56
Oct 6.00    6.62    7.22    7.79    6.99    
Nov 6.10    6.72    7.44    8.18    7.57    
Dec 6.08    6.73    7.36    8.12    7.05
```